How to leave my solution to an ode

Hi, I was wondering when doing these types of questions, is it appropriate to leave my solution as $y^2 = RHS$? or should I have it as $y = \pm\sqrt{RHS}$. Because I see solutions online keeping it in the first form $y^2$ instead of squaring both sides. Thanks in advance

You have an initial condition. Therefore it is expected that you select the correct branch of the square root. So in general the solution will be in the square-rooted form. In some cases it might be sufficient to restrict the solution with inequalities that make the selection of the branch unique.

Sorry could you elaborate I’m not sure I quite follow? Do you mean that since the initial condition is positive I should select the positive root?

In the presented case, yes. The final formula should be correct at least at the initial point.
